# How to troubleshoot "Expected one CustomField but found 0" error?

Tags: custom-fields, error

When I try to open **Contacts** of some Smart Groups, CiviCRM gives me error:

**Expected one CustomField but found 0**

[image]

All parent Smart Groups that include faulty Smart Groups are also rendering the same error (can't open contacts).

If I try to delete these Smart Groups, I get Network Error.
[image]

When in **Groups tab of Contact profile** I open Smart Groups subsection, it remains empty (no Smart groups are listed). Not sure if for all contacts or only those that are included in faulty smart groups.

How can I fix this error?

CiviCRM 4.7.14 on Drupal 7.59

## DEBUG INFO (sample 1)

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Expected one CustomField but found 0"

```
#0 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4491): civicrm_api3("CustomField", "getvalue", (Array:3))
#1 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(452): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::isCustomDateField("custom_52")
#2 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(111): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::decodeRelativeFields((Array:11), "custom_52", ">=", "35")
#3 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(197): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::getFormValues("custom_52")
#4 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(590): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::getSearchParams("88")
#5 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3054): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))
#6 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2947): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache("132", NULL, "contact_a", "=")
#7 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1794): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group((Array:5))
#8 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2021): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), NULL)
#9 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(502): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(NULL)
#10 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(466): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#11 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(236): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:1), (Array:9), (Array:16), FALSE, FALSE, 1, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, 1)
#12 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search.php(832): CRM_Contact_Selector->__construct(NULL, (Array:5), (Array:1), (Array:9), 256, FALSE, TRUE, "smog", (Array:9))
#13 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Basic.php(188): CRM_Contact_Form_Search->postProcess()
#14 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search.php(718): CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Basic->postProcess()
#15 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Basic.php(134): CRM_Contact_Form_Search->preProcess()
#16 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(531): CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Basic->preProcess()
#17 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#18 sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Basic), "display")
#19 sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Basic), "display")
#20 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#21 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), (Array:0))
#22 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#23 sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#24 sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#25 /includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("group", "search")
#26 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#27 {main}
```

## DEBUG INFO (sample 2)

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Expected one CustomField but found 0"

```
#0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4491): civicrm_api3("CustomField", "getvalue", (Array:3))
#1 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(452): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::isCustomDateField("custom_21")
#2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(111): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::decodeRelativeFields((Array:10), "custom_21", "BETWEEN", (Array:2))
#3 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php(197): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::getFormValues("custom_21")
#4 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(590): CRM_Contact_BAO_SavedSearch::getSearchParams("54")
#5 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3054): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))
#6 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2947): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache("89", NULL, "contact_a", "=")
#7 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1794): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group((Array:5))
#8 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2021): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), NULL)
#9 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(502): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(NULL)
#10 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(466): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#11 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4330): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:1), (Array:1), (Array:16), TRUE, FALSE, 1, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, "AND", NULL)
#12 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Group.php(200): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery((Array:1), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE)
#13 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(704): CRM_Contact_BAO_Group::getMember("89", FALSE)
#14 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3054): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))
#15 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2947): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache("77", NULL, "contact_a", "=")
#16 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1794): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group((Array:5))
#17 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2021): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), NULL)
#18 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(502): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(NULL)
#19 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(466): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#20 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4330): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:1), (Array:1), (Array:16), TRUE, FALSE, 1, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, "AND", NULL)
#21 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Group.php(200): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery((Array:1), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE)
#22 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(704): CRM_Contact_BAO_Group::getMember("77", FALSE)
#23 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3054): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))
#24 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2947): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache((Array:1), NULL, "contact_a", "IN")
#25 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1794): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group((Array:5))
#26 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2021): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), NULL)
#27 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(502): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(NULL)
#28 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(466): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#29 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4330): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:1), (Array:1), (Array:16), TRUE, FALSE, 1, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, "AND", NULL)
#30 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(229): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery((Array:1), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE)
#31 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(208): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::add((Array:206))
#32 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Group/Page/Group.php(144): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::loadAll()
#33 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(172): CRM_Group_Page_Group->browse(NULL, NULL)
#34 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run((Array:2), NULL)
#35 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#36 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#37 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#38 /includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("group")
#39 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#40 {main}
```

Could it be connected with some **Summary Fields extension** that has somehow messed up some custom fields? In any case, disabling **Summary Fields**, changing its settings or updating to newest version **does not** solve the issue.

Comment: Can you reach the Manage group listings? And then see the search criteria for any of the affected smart groups? (Settings> Edit Smart Group Criteria). Might give you a clue as to the fields the smart groups are based on.

Comment: there have been some issues with 'on hold' showing up in Smart Groups so check that when you 'edit' the saved search

Comment: We can better answer this question if you post the debugging and backtrace info.  Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling** and turn on debugging and backtrace.  Repeat the steps that lead to this error and you should get a much more detailed error message.  Please edit your question to include the expanded error + backtrace as text (i.e. not a screenshot).

Comment: @CraigAlmond I'm afraid that **Edit Smart Group Criteria** renders the same error: *Expected one CustomField but found 0*

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Thank you! I added one instance of error with debug / backtrace enabled.

Answer (score 1):

These smart groups include custom fields that no longer exist.  In the first case, it's the custom field with id of 52; in the second the id is 21.  These smart groups should have their criteria modified to reflect the fact that these groups no longer exist.

Comment: How can I do it, if the standard way - **Edit Smart Group Criteria** - produces the same error?

Answer (score 1):

@junglebird on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm provided a solution to delete such groups via API Explorer.

Smart groups also have an entry in **civicrm_saved_search**.  I think it would be safer to make a list of the group IDs, go to **Support >> Developer >> API Explorer** and select Entity of **Group**, Action of **Delete**, and set the ID accordingly.

Comment: This is me - I should try harder to consolidate my CiviCRM usernames :)